# Not able to tweet video through twitter using UIActivityViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

Not able to share the video on twitter through UIActivityViewController.

Text and local video storage works fine. So authentication is not an issue.

If video is stored in the app itself, then the share works fine
Path URL

> file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B7855569-3254-4CC2-9573-254D09528E38/podhunt.app/PlugIns/podhunt-shareExtension.appex/demo_video.mp4

If the path is below, then the twitter share does not work
Path Url

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/5831780C-50AF-41FA-8435-941CAC47EBE6/Documents/10c41d4a-c161-4c78-bc61-ca789804a982.mp4

**This does not work**

```
    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl) { location, response, error in
    guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
    do {
           try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [destinationUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
               self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
             }
           } catch {
      }
    }.resume()
```

**This works**

```
URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl) { location, response, error in
    guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
    do {
           try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
           guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo_video", ofType:"mp4") else {
               return
            }
               let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [URL(fileURLWithPath: path)],applicationActivities: nil)
               self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
             }
           } catch {
      }
    }.resume()
```

I am working on iOS app extension.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved. Apparently I was sharing mp3 file as an mp4 to twitter which it does not recognize. You cannot share mp3 file to twitter as it does not support audio format.